# Cannot exclude an external package from server bundle file using vite and solid plugin

Tags: vite, supabase, solid, solid-start

It's been 2 days now that I am struggling with this issue of not being able to exclude @supabase/supabase-js and its dependancies from the final server.js file. I am using Cloudflare workers solid adapter. I've tried all possible combinations to mark the library as external with no luck. Here is my vite.ts file.

```
import solid from 'solid-start/vite'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import cloudflare from 'solid-start-cloudflare-workers'
import createExternal from 'vite-plugin-external'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    solid({
      ssr: false,
      exclude: ['@supabase/supabase-js', 'node_modules'],
      adapter: cloudflare({
        wranglerConfigPath: true,
      }),
    }),
    createExternal({
      externals: {
        supabase: '@supabase/supabase-js',
      },
    }),
  ],
  envPrefix: 'PUBLIC_',
  server: {
    port: 8010,
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['node_modules', '@supabase/supabase-js'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          '@supabase/supabase-js': '@supabase/supabase-js',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    disabled: true,
    exclude: ['node_modules', '@supabase/supabase-js'],
  },
  ssr: {
    external: ['node_modules', '@supabase/supabase-js'],
  },
})
```

Resulting `server.js` has traces of supabase being bundles into the file along with its dependencies.

```
import manifestJSON from '__STATIC_CONTENT_MANIFEST';
import Stream from 'stream';
import http from 'http';
import Url from 'url';
import require$$0$2 from 'punycode';
import https from 'https';
import zlib from 'zlib';
import require$$2 from 'events';
import require$$0$3 from 'tty';
import require$$1$1 from 'util';
import require$$3 from 'fs';
import require$$4 from 'net';
import require$$0$5 from 'crypto';
...
```

I need to end up with server simply having depencies imported as:

```
import {createServer} from '@supabase/supabase-js'
```

It's probably worth mentioning that I am using typescript and there is a tsconfig.json file with the following configs:

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/solid.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["solid-start/env"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "@supabase/supabase-js"]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried to add externals into config file with the same result every time.